# Procedure takes long time to execute query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following SP for SQL Server. Strangely the SP has weired behaviour when executing the query

```
Select @max_backup_session_time = Max(MachineStat.BackupSessionTime) from MachineStat     where MachineStat.MachineID = @machine_id;
```

It takes 1 second if the MachineStat table has rows pertaining to @machine_id but if there are no rows for a @machine_id then it takes more than half a minute to execute. Can someone please help me understand this.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @MachineStatsMId TABLE (
  MachineId         INT NULL,
  BackupSessiontime BIGINT NULL,
  MachineGroupName  NVARCHAR(128) NULL )
DECLARE @machine_id AS INT;
DECLARE @Machine_group_id AS INT;
DECLARE @machine_group_name AS NVARCHAR(128);
DECLARE @max_backup_session_time AS BIGINT;

SET @machine_id = 0;
SET @Machine_group_id = 0;
SET @machine_group_name = '';

DECLARE MachinesCursor CURSOR FOR
  SELECT m.MachineId,
         m.MachineGroupId,
         mg.MachineGroupName
  FROM   Machines m,
         MachineGroups mg
  WHERE  m.MachineGroupId = mg.MachineGroupId;

OPEN MachinesCursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM MachinesCursor INTO @machine_id, @machine_group_id, @machine_group_name;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  BEGIN
      SELECT @max_backup_session_time = Max(MachineStat.BackupSessionTime)
      FROM   MachineStat
      WHERE  MachineStat.MachineID = @machine_id;

      INSERT INTO @MachineStatsMId
      VALUES      (@machine_id,
                   @max_backup_session_time,
                   @machine_group_name);

      FETCH NEXT FROM MachinesCursor INTO @machine_id, @machine_group_id, @machine_group_name;
  END;

SELECT *
FROM   @MachineStatsMId;

CLOSE MachinesCursor;

DEALLOCATE MachinesCursor;
GO
```

Comment: Why are you using a cursor? Why are you using old-style joins?

Comment: If you must use a cursor and you're not using the cursor to perform updates or move in both directions, make it LOCAL FAST_FORWARD. (A cursor isn't actually needed for this, though.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternate version that avoids a cursor and table variable entirely, uses proper (modern) joins and schema prefixes, and *should* run a lot quicker than what you have. If it still runs slow in certain scenarios, please post the actual execution plan for that scenario as well as an actual execution plan for the fast scenario.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.procname
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  SELECT 
    m.MachineId, 
    BackupSessionTime = MAX(ms.BackupSessionTime), 
    mg.MachineGroupName
  FROM dbo.Machines AS m
  INNER JOIN dbo.MachineGroups AS mg 
    ON m.MachineGroupId = mg.MachineGroupId
  INNER JOIN dbo.MachineStat AS ms -- you may want LEFT OUTER JOIN here, not sure
    ON m.MachineId = ms.MachineID
  GROUP BY m.MachineID, mg.MachineGroupName;
END
GO
```